# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1319, 245]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am facing issues related to  `train_test_split`:

```
final = []
final.append(dataset)
final.append(dataset1)
X = dataset[:,0:2]
y = dataset1[:,2]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\thesis code\TC_code.py", line 73, in <module>
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2172, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 299, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 262, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1319, 245]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the shape of both `X` and `y`. It must have same number of rows.

```
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

if X.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
  print("X and y rows are mismatched, check dataset again")
```

#### Note:

- **The rows of both X and y should be same**

You have used **`dataset`** for `X` whereas **`dataset1`** for `y` which should be the main error in your code.

See here:

```
X = dataset[:,0:2]
y = dataset1[:,2]
```

**dataset** and **dataset1** are two different dataframes which might represent two different data.

Comment: Now, Unimplemented Error:  Cast string to float is not supported.

model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, verbose=1)